# Load an ontology in Protege from a SPARQL endpoint

Tags: sparql, protege

I'm simply wondering if I can load an ontology in **Protege** (or **Web Protege**) from a `SPARQL` endpoint.

The option "**open from URL...**" loads regular `rdf` files and it seems not working with `SPARQL` endpoints.

**EDIT**

Whit *load* I mean loading all the triples coming from a query result processed by a `SPARQL` endpoint. For example, I might load them all with:

```
CONSTRUCT {?s ?p ?o} WHERE {?s ?p ?o}
```

Comment: Are you talking about a particular endpoint? And what means "load"? In general, that can't work for good reasons, imagine loading DBpedia into Protege, that won't work. In general, it will not be feasible for any larger dataset. The way to go is to write a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` query that retrieves the triples you're interested in, save this to disk, and then load it into Protege.

Comment: In this case, I'd like to load (i.e., to visualize the available triples, see the edit) from a local SPARQL endpoint. It's a very small ontology that I manage in a triple store and I'd like to load data directly from there. As you pointed out, Protege cannot handle large datasets, whether they come from local files, URLs or from SPARQL endpoints. It would be great loading directly from an endpoint (or from a query) in the future : )

Comment: I see. You could create a plugin of type "Action". Developing such a plugin is more or less trivial, less than 50 lines of code.

Comment: By the way, your example is the wrong way, you should only use CONSTRUCT queries which return proper RDF triples. Allowing SELECT queries won't guarantee triples as result and even for `SELECT ?s ?p ?o` internally you'd have to convert them to RDF triples because the main backend is OWL API which needs OWL as format.

Comment: +1 Well put. I'm going to correct. I'm not familiar with Protege plugins, but I will look into this. Thanks for your help @AKSW

Comment: Oh, I was forgetting: is this plugin type suitable also for the Web version?

Comment: It's not that difficult, you even don't have to start from scratch, here is already an example project: https://github.com/protegeproject/protege-plugin-examples - it wraps, several plugin types but the interesting one for you is the menu type: https://github.com/protegeproject/protege-plugin-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/edu/stanford/bmir/protege/examples/menu

Comment: well, for the Web version I don't know. I mean, the source code is online I guess but you'd have to host your own WebProtege in order to use additional features develped by you

Comment: Just to give you an idea how the workflow should be: take SPARQL CONSTRUCT query and endpoint URL -> run query via RDF4J or Apache Jena API -> in case of Apache Jena it will return a `Model` which you could directly pipe into an `InputStream` that can be read by OWL API resp. the Protege ModelManager

Comment: Another idea: you have the endpoint URL so you can create the request URL easily. the general format is `http://ENDPOINT_URL?query=QUERY_STRING` - for example, open `http://dbpedia.org/sparql?query=describe%20dbr:Leipzig` in Protege via **open from URL** - I totally forgot this is the most simple way, just create the request URL.

Comment: Superdooper solution @AKSW! If you want to summarize your hints in a comprehensive answer, I'll be happy to accept it! However, I'm looking forward to seeing Protege fully interacts with `SPARQL` endpoints (i.e., read / save data) :)

Comment: Protege is OWL-API(v4)-based with its default in-memory reference implementation, so it cannot handle large datasets. OWL-API-impl has another restriction: it can hold only OWL2 data. A sparql-dl plugin uses the same things - so there is always a conversion `axiom -> triple`. For real data it would not work, for small - maybe, but buggy. API-parsers (even v5) work badly with anything, that has not been produced by the OWL-API itself, especially if RDF has custom []-lists. But, there is a Protege fork based on OWL-API v5,  and it can work with ONT-API -  a RDF-centric OWL-API impl alternative.